# How to clear the window in tmux and node inside of tmux?

Tags: node.js, shell, tmux

In shell, CTRL-L will clear my window. If I am running tmux it will not. Typing `'clear'` will. Additionally, C-L or `'clear'` will not clear the window when I am running node inside of tmux. I would like to know if someone can help me with a script that I would put in my `tmux.conf` that would let me bind C-L to clear the window in a tmux shell as well as inside node running in tmux.

I only used some different lines that GPT spit out. One of them got C-L to clear node but would not work in the tmux shell. Another option it gave worked in both by clearing the window but it would leave new inputs at the top.

Comment: `bind -n C-l clear-history`

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your suggestion, but the clear-history command  doesn't work for me in tmux. If I type clear it will clear the window though. However, clear does not work for me when I am in Node.